# How to bind directly properties in xaml uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        //public static dynamic resource;

        public  ResourceModel vm = new ResourceModel();        

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();              
        }
     }


public class ResourceModel 
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _resource;
        public Dictionary<string, string> Resource
        {
            get { return _resource; }
            set
            {
               _resource=Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Xaml Code**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding vm.Resource[Account] ,Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="15" Margin="10 0 30 0" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
```

**Description**
 I want to bind my textblock from the ResourceModel   without DataContext and Name of textblock. Only i need binding using property Name.

Comment: Use x:Bind? `Text="{x:Bind vm.Resource[Account] ,Mode=TwoWay}" `.

Comment: @mm8 Error Invalid binding path 'vm.Resource[Account]' invalid index

Comment: @mm8 how to pass string "Account"

Answer (score 1):

There are a few places which you're missing out. Below is some information on em:

1. The `Binding` is searching for a data context which is not available. In case you don't have a `viewmodel` and you want to use the legacy `binding` to bind UI elements to the code behind you need to add `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"` in your `<Page>` tag of `xaml`. This will tell the Binding Engine that you're binding to the code behind.
2. Also, you can't bind to fields, you can only bind to `properties` as fields don't have a `get` and `set`. So in your code behind your `vm` is a field and not a property. Change it to `public ResourceModel vm { get; set; } = new ResourceModel();` and it'll start working.

---

That being said, there are 3 ways you can go about it:

### 1. using `binding` to codebehind:

In the `<page>` tag add the `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"` for telling the binding engine that you'll be binding to code behind.

Your `textblock` code looks like below:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding vm.Resource[Account]}"/>
```

I don't understand why is the `Mode` set to `two way` as it's a `Textblock` and is un-editable and legacy `binding` is by default `oneWay`.

### 2. using `binding` with `ResourceModel`

Another way would be to set the data context of the `textblock` to directly bind to the Model. below is the code:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Resource[Account]}">
       <TextBlock.DataContext>
            <local:ResourceModel/>
       </TextBlock.DataContext>
  </TextBlock>
```

### 3. use `x:bind` for code behind binding

The `x:bind` by default binds to the code behind so you can use `x:bind` instead of binding. The issue you face with `x:bind` is because you can't set in the key in xaml when using x:bind. Use converters and then pass in your key as a converter parameter and it'll all start to work just fine. if you do plan on using it below is the xaml code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind vm.Resource,Converter={StaticResource DictionaryValueFetcher},ConverterParameter='account'}"/>
```